# wordpress .htaccess rule for folder structure giving 404 error

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am creating a job search site using wordpress. I want to create a custom .htaccess rule so that when user search jobs in a form then first part will go as folder structure and rest will add as query param.

This will be only if we query parameter ?find= any-value be in url
rest pages want as it is like
http://example.com/contact/

I want :-

http://example.com/?find=any-value&job_location=Austin,TX&findjobs=Search

to become :-

http://example.com/any-value?job_location=Austin,TX&findjobs=Search

my permalink setting is like :-

http://example.com/sample-post/

QA .htaccess code

```
    
    # Special redirects
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^find=([^/]*)$ 
    RewriteRule ^/?$ /%1\/? [R=301,L]
    # BEGIN WordPress
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    
    # END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `wp_redirect` function in `template_redirect` hook.

Can be added on `functions.php`

Example:

```
function my_redirect_function() {
    // check if argument is set
    if ( $_GET['find'] ) {
        // get site url
        $url = get_site_url() . '/' . $_GET['find'];

        // clone GET arguments
        $query = $_GET;

        // remove the find argument
        unset( $query['find'] );

        // add all get arguments to the new url
        $url = add_query_arg( $query, $url );

        // redirect to the generated url
        wp_redirect( $url );
        exit();
    }
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_redirect_function' );
```

Links:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_redirect/
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect

Comment: As you see my parameter ?find=any-value is taking different value on all new search. would you please give an example ?

Comment: Not tested, but explain what you need to do

Comment: I want to make this search form to work same as https://nerdyhire.com/ when user search any term it will add keyword as page with trailing other variables same as nerdyhire.

Comment: I tried but no luck it is redirecting but same 404 error with page and also after redirecting $_GET['find'] is loosing.

Comment: Maybe is because the page doesn't exist. (`http://example.com/any-value?job_l...`). did you create an page with this slug?

Comment: no this page is not created as this page is changing with search term. I want to take everything on index.php so that url willbe like above but show custom from my plugin page any middle way to do it?

Comment: Wordpress treats every page that doesn't exist as 404. The right way to do this is tell wordpress that this page exists, but this isn't so easy for beginners. You can delete your `404.php` file. This way every 404 request will go to `index.php`. If you wan't to know the right way search about custom URLs or tell me.

Answer (score 0):

+1 to you Maxwell Thank you very much Below are the working code for others ;)

```
add_action('parse_request', 'vm_parse_request');

function vm_parse_request(&$wp) {
    if (isset($_GET['find'])) {
        // get site url
        $url = get_site_url() . '/' . $_GET['find'];
        // clone GET arguments
        $query = $_GET;
        // remove the find argument
        unset($query['find']);
        // add all get arguments to the new url
        $url = add_query_arg($query, $url);
        // redirect to the generated url
        wp_redirect($url);
        exit();
    }
    if (isset($_GET['findjobs'])) {
        // setup hooks and filters to generate virtual movie page
        add_action('template_redirect', 'vm_template_redir');
        //add_filter('the_posts', 'vm_createdummypost');
        //add_filter('the_content', 'j2c_job_display');
        // remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
    }
}

function vm_template_redir() {
    // Reset currrently set 404 flag as this is a plugin-generated page
    global $wp_query, $post;
    $wp_query->is_404 = false;
    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    $urlslug = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    $urlslug = explode("?", $urlslug[1]);
    $post = get_post(165, OBJECT);
    //$post->content = "hello testhere";
    setup_postdata($post);
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'j2c_enqueue', 9999);
    $_GET['find'] = str_replace("/", "", $urlslug[0]);
   // add_filter('the_content', 'j2c_job_display');
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $template_path = plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'template/page.php';
    include( $template_path); // child

    exit;
}
```